# Json returning null JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to read some YouTube json data and for some reason it is returning null in the console.

I am trying to retrive the information from this link:
https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MpUj-Aua48&format=json

Front End code:

```
var title;
var videoId;
var jsonObj;

ytVideoTitle(title, videoId).then(function(result) { jsonObj = 
JSON.parse(result); console.log(jsonObj); });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because title is not nested under html. Try

```
.then(json => console.log(json.html))
```

or

```
.then(json => console.log(json.title))
```

Comment: Same result, null. Anymore ideas?

Comment: Try just `console.log(json)`. See if that data is as you expect.

Comment: Hi, I now have it working so that it displays all the data from the query, is there now a way so that I can display only the title field?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling your code like this:

```
var title; 
var videoId; 
ytVideoTitle(title, videoId).then(function(result) { console.log(result); });
```

You should have your backend code like this:

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';

export function ytVideoTitle(title, videoId) {

  return fetch("https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch? v=2MpUj-Aua48&format=json", {method: "get"})
    .then( (httpResponse) => {
      if (httpResponse.ok) {
        return httpResponse.json();
      } else {
        return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
      }
    } ).catch(err => console.log(err));
 }
```

since your last `.then(json => console.log(json.html["title"]))` does not return the json object, so you won't get it as the return of your `ytVideoTitle` function.

Comment: Previously tried this, it still says 'null'. Any other ideas?

Comment: Post what you get in the console by doing: `console.log(json)`

Comment: Uhm, it seems like the request is failing. Try to put a `console.log` into the else block or look into the network tab in the console. Are you getting a 200 status in the network tab?

Comment: You have a space in the URL you are making the request to. Did you remove it in the code you are testing? I get a 404 if I don't.

Comment: Yeah, I removed the space. Still not working, still syaing null.

Comment: I edited my main answer with some code. I also edited your question but it was a  mistake.

Comment: This is now displaying the json text, thank you.  How would I filter through this then to get one element?

Comment: If it is a plain json string you could get an object by `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(yourJSONString)`

Comment: I tried this code:
`var jsonObj = JSON.parse("title")
console.log(jsonObj);`

And it gave me this error: `Unexpected token i in JSON at position 1`

Have i done something wrong?

Comment: It should be like: `ytVideoTitle(title, videoId).then(function(result) { jsonObj = JSON.parse(result); console.log(jsonObj); });`

If in `result` you are getting a string that represents the JSON you are fetching from the YouTube API, then if you pass that string into the `JSON.parse()` function you should be able to access the `title` property as an object.

Comment: Whichever way I seem to try, I keep getting this error: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` I'm new to working with json so any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Could you edit your question with all your latest code?

Comment: Essentially, want I need to do now is just get the value of title from the json file into a JavaScript variable.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 `fetch("https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch? v=2MpUj-Aua48&format=json", {method: "get"})
      .then( (httpResponse) => {
        if (httpResponse) {
          return httpResponse.json();
        } else {
          return console.log("Fetch did not succeed");
        }
      } )
      .catch(error => console.log(error));`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately this is giving me the same result, saying null in the console.  Any other ideas?

Just to clear this up, the file you are looking at is in the backend and I am calling it in the front end with this code:

`var title;
var videoId;

ytVideoTitle(title, videoId).then(function(result) {
console.log(result);`